# Prahalada vs Abhimanyu story misunderstanding

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, advaita, vaishnavism, smarta

I have heard two stories and one seem to be in conflict with another. Please correct my misunderstanding.

In the story of Prahalada, Prahalada was educated by Narada (while Prahalada was inside his mother) and got the information even while his mother slept.

But in the story of Abhimanyu, While Abhimanyu was in his mother's womb, his father Arjuna would tell how to get in and get out of the Chakravyuhu. But, later, it is said that, Abhimanyu's mother was sleeping when Arjuna told the story of Chakravyuhu and that was the reason why Abhimanyu was able to get inside the Chakravyuhu but not get out.

My question is, In the story of Prahalada, Prahalada was able to listen even when his mother slept. But in the case of Abhimanyu, he was not able to get the information when his mother slept.

What could be the reason.

Comment: It's not that Abhimanyu couldn't listen. Krishna stopped saying it, because Abhimanyu's mother slept.

Comment: Sage Asta vakra repriminded his father while still in womb when his mother slept, Asked his father to go to sleep instead of burining the night oil on scripture for which his father cursed his unborn son to have cripling while born.  so this puts that till a kid is born the baby in the womb remembers its previous birth and constantly prays not to repeat the same mistake after this birth, but during birth by the force of Samana Vayu the child forgets all its pervious birth